# How to find span in found element in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to find text in found element by selenium. [Look at this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/ACCSTORE-Portable-Wardrobe-Clothing-Organiser/dp/B08PV5FZ12/ref=sr_1_5?crid=3DCM24F9AAXHI&keywords=wardrobe&qid=1672314673&sprefix=wardrobe%2Caps%2C168&sr=8-5&th=1). For example there I would like click in 'secure transaction' at product card

I try to do it by this

```
class ProductCard:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    div = (By.XPATH, "//div[@class='a-box-inner a-padding-base']")

    def easyToAssemble(self):
            self.driver.find_element(*ProductCard.div).find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Secure transaction')]").click()

            return True
```

This code doesn't work, I suspect that problem is there

```
self.driver.find_element(*ProductCard.div).find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Secure transaction')]")
```

I have no idea how to solve the issue.

I want to know how to find element in found element by selenium in python

Comment: That element can't be clicked on link you shared

Comment: So tell me how to click e.g `//a[@target='_blank'][normalize-space()='Details']` or anything else in `div` declared above

Comment: I'm not sure I explain correctyly. I try get element in div which has been found

Comment: This should work fine `self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Secure transaction')]").click()`

Comment: It works but I declared parent here `div = (By.XPATH, "//div[@class='a-box-inner a-padding-base']")` and later I try find child, just in this div, not on whole DOM, just in this div

Comment: You can try this:     div = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='a-box-inner a-padding-base']")

div.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Secure transaction')]").click()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error : Element <span>...</span> is not clickable at point (855,
565).

OK! So, let's click on its parent.

You just need to add `/..` at the end of your xpath.

```py
self.driver.find_element(*ProductCard.div).find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Secure transaction')]/..").click()
```

Comment: Could I please information how to type it in google? I want read about it

Comment: You're welcome.
It refers to Xpath Syntax. Not much to read, but good to know. There are many sources available for it, you can see any one you like.
(https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm so apreciated. That's much importat me